# `std::filesystem::directory_iterator` compiler issue

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, c++17, std-filesystem

Many people (e.g [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51252829/stdfilesystemdirectory-iterator-linker-issue-c17), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149878/experimentalfilesystem-linker-error)) have asked about how to get `std::filesystem::directory_iterator` to work, but I'm still having trouble after I've read those.

I am trying to build a small static library. After adding in the directory iterator into some source files, I updated my gcc, and added the `-lstdc++fs` bit, but nothing seems to work because I keep getting the error message

```
fatal error: filesystem: No such file or directory
 #include <filesystem>
```

If I type `gcc --version`, I get

```
gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) 7.3.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

And if I type `gcc-8 --version` I get

```
gcc-8 (Ubuntu 8.1.0-1ubuntu1) 8.1.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Here's my little shell script that compiles everything. I've tried a few other variations, too.

```bash
EIGEN=/usr/include/eigen3

cd ./bin
for file in ../src/*cpp; do
        g++ -std=c++11 -fPIC -c -I$EIGEN -I../include -O3 $file "-lstdc++fs"
done    
ar crv libfoo.a *.o
cd ..
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us what's wrong.

Comment: And how do you attempt to create an actual executable program that uses libfoo.a?

Comment: @JohnZwinck sorry. It's this: fatal error: filesystem: No such file or directory

Comment: Have you tried to replace `g++` with `g++-8`?

Comment: And it's not a linker issue. It's the compiler that does not find the header.

Comment: @xskxzr yes I have. And yeah that makes sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<filesystem>` was added to the C++ standard library only with C++17.

`g++ 7.3` (your default `g++`) is not fully compliant on this score. It will not locate `<filesystem>` with `-std=c++17`.
Reasonably, it will not locate `<filesystem>` with `-std=c++11`, which your posted script is asking it to.
But it will locate `<experimental/filesystem>` with `std=c++11` or later.

You also have `g++-8` (presumably g++ 8.1/8.2). It will locate `<filesystem>` with `std=c++17`:

```
$ cat main.cpp 
#include <filesystem>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
$ g++-8 -std=c++17 main.cpp && echo $?
0
```

And funnily enough, it will also do so with either `std=c++11` or `std=c++14`:

```
$ g++-8 -std=c++11 main.cpp && echo $?
0
$ g++-8 -std=c++14 main.cpp && echo $?
0
```

With `g++-8` you won't need to link the transitional library `libstdc++fs`.

(Incidentally, the smart money always enables rigorous warnings in compilation:
`... -Wall -Wextra ...`)

Comment: thanks @MikeKinghan `g++-8 -std=c++17 -fPIC -c -Wall -Wextra -I$EIGEN -I../include -O3 $file` worked for me, but c++11/14 didn't for some reason